# Async Update Session Data

Tags: c#, session, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I find several answers bashing use of session state in async fashion, eg.

- [Sessions in Asynchronous design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118236/sessions-in-asynchronous-design)
- [Asynchronous threads and session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096789/asynchronous-threads-and-session)

Are there some conditions under which updating session from async thread will not or can not work?

My use case is as follows:

In app, user profile data is stored in session. Aim to asynchronously refresh the profile data when an admin changes a user's name, groups, or other profile info, etc.

Async thrust:
poll a database table that stores the user id's whose data has changed.
if data matches current user id, refresh profile data, remove id from table

I find the following code updates a session key asynchronously.

```
public class MyAsyncUpdateController : Controller
{
    public static string MyKey = "myKey";
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        Session[MyKey] = "Init Data: Updated at " + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

        Task.Factory.StartNew(session =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            var _session = (HttpSessionState)session;

            if (_session != null)
                _session[MyKey] = "Async Data: Updated at " + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay ;

        }, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session);

        return RedirectToAction("OtherAction");
    }

    public ActionResult OtherAction()
    {
        string result = "";
        if (Session != null && Session[MyKey] != null)
            result=  Session[MyKey].ToString();

        return Content(result);
       //Refresh until see updated timestamp
    }


}
```

Are there any additional considerations or protections - besides a null check - that I should take when writing to session data from the async task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*Using `Task.Factory.StartNew` in ASP.NET is dangerous and may lead to unexpected behavior*](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html)

> The reason is that the ASP.NET runtime has no idea that you’ve queued this work, so it’s not aware that the background work even exists. For a variety of reasons, IIS/ASP.NET has to occasionally recycle your application. If you have background work running when this recycling takes place, that work will mysteriously disappear

Moreover, `HttpContext.Current.Session` is not thread-safe. When consuming multiple requests asynchronously on the same key you may run into race conditions leading to invalid data.

I would strongly advise you to look at alternatives:

1. Use a persistent queue (as Stephan suggests in his blogpost) such as MSMQ or Azure MB.
2. Use either [`HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.queuebackgroundworkitem(v=vs.110).aspx) or alternativley Stephans [`BackgroundTaskManager`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AspNetBackgroundTasks) which register work with the ASP.NET ThreadPool.
3. Consider running this code synchronously

You should also read more about [*Returning Early From ASP.NET Requests*](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/returning-early-from-aspnet-requests.html) and *[Using Task.Run in a syncronous asp.net controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22709855/using-task-run-in-a-syncronous-asp-net-controller)*